# Are OCMock objects really instances of a class?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, ocmock

When we create a mock object with OCMock, for example

```
id classMock = OCMClassMock([SomeClass class]);
```

is the classMock a real object of SomeClass in the background, or is it some sort of a hack?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class mocks are instances of `OCClassMockObject` ([source](https://github.com/erikdoe/ocmock/blob/master/Source/OCMock/OCClassMockObject.h)). The implementation uses the normal forwarding mechanism, which I wouldn't call a hack. That said, partial mocks are (obviously) real instances and there is a bit of "magic" going on when it comes to their class.